# Effect of magnets on LCD monitors?

Tags: magnetics, monitor

Do speaker magnet's have any effect on the LCD monitor. because few month's ago one of mine went faulty dark patches produced on it which when pressed behaved like liquid i.e. when i pressed the the sreaded and even i was able to press it and make it move one side og the screen. When i asked to one person he said that it because of the speakers i kept beside it?

Comment: Speaker magnets will affect old CRT monitors but should have no effect on modern LCD monitors. Dark patches on LCDs are usually caused by excess force applied to the screen.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: @user3624 I am not taking about some miracle.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a stack of powerful rare earth magnets (the type that can give you serious blisters when your skin gets caught inbetween) but it had no effect only LCD monitor whatsoever. Myth disproved as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: ok thank's just wanted to know actually the screen was faulty but wanted to check was that man corredt or not so you are sure that my speakers will have no effect on the LCD tft monitor even in long terms

Answer (score 1):

No, magnets do not affect the LCD monitor operation in any way. They affect CRTs because of the deflection of the internal electron beam. This is because of the force applied to a charged particle moving in a magnetic field.